# centos7 crash when systemctl start docker successed

Tags: linux, centos, crash, centos-7, linux-kernel

### [phenomenon]

1、I enter the command `systemctl start docker` from centos7, the centos7 crashed after docker successfully started.(It's reproducible)
2、Docker used to be available until I ran 3 ZooKeeper. （i used to run many mysql on docker）
3、I had start `kdump` and you can see the command on log, but no any crash log can be found
4、The log(/var/log/message) has been attached at the end

### [environment]

system version: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
kernel: 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
hardware:

- mainboard:c602 x79
- cpu:e5-2651v2
- network card: rtl8111e
- Ram： 32GB

docker version:20.10.8

### /var/log/messages(Suspicious areas，the date has been remove because )

```
:23:47 localhost kdumpctl: kexec: loaded kdump kernel
:23:47 localhost kdumpctl: Starting kdump: [OK]
:23:47 localhost systemd: Started Crash recovery kernel arming.
:23:47 localhost systemd: Reached target Multi-User System.
:23:47 localhost systemd: Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
:23:47 localhost systemd: Started Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection 10s After Completed Startup.
:23:47 localhost systemd: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
:23:47 localhost systemd: Startup finished in 2.417s (kernel) + 2.908s (initrd) + 46.787s (userspace) = 7min 8.486s.
:24:17 localhost systemd: Starting Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection...
:24:17 localhost systemd: Started Stop Read-Ahead Data Collection.
:25:01 localhost systemd: getty@tty1.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
:25:01 localhost systemd: Stopped Getty on tty1.
:25:01 localhost systemd: Started Getty on tty1.
:33:01 localhost kernel: usb 2-1.8.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
:37:39 localhost systemd: Starting containerd container runtime...
:37:39 localhost systemd: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
:37:40 localhost systemd: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
:37:40 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:40.979654305Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3 version=1.4.9
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.017880066Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.046969355Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.052233945Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found.\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.052286193Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.052349781Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.052378479Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.052471777Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.053092423Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.053398089Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.053434144Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.053489834Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.053514718Z" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087627234Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087682763Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087764475Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.introspection-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087827808Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087858867Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.content-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087897052Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087930083Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.images-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087958627Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.087987536Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.088012320Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.088040922Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.088209635Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.088383718Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups\"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089300773Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service\"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089376417Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.restart\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089480059Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089516019Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089542363Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089566512Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.events\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089590946Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089616588Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.images\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089641570Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089665884Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089689848Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.opt\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089825125Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089860973Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089888395Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.version\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.089911617Z" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.105623258Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.105746316Z" level=info msg=serving... address=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
:37:41 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:41.106479058Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.174141s"
:37:41 localhost systemd: Started containerd container runtime.
:37:41 localhost systemd: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.445670896Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.499983847Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.500030593Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.500079390Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.500112412Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.584785856Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.584828999Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.584865289Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:42.584891670Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
:37:42 localhost kernel: TECH PREVIEW: Overlay filesystem may not be fully supported.#012Please review provided documentation for limitations.
:37:43 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:43.627726084Z" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
:37:46 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:46.671085826Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
:37:47 localhost kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
:37:47 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:47.752780431Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER' failed: iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory#012#012Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER' failed: iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory#012#012Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER' failed: iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load target `DOCKER':No such file or directory#012#012Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D PREROUTING' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -D OUTPUT' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -F DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t nat -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:47 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
:37:48 localhost kernel: ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.1821] manager: (br-3e8779b04137): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
:37:48 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-3e8779b04137 -o br-3e8779b04137 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:48 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:48.361956940Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-3e8779b04137 already part of docker zone, returning"
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4460] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-3e8779b04137: link is not ready
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4506] ifcfg-rh: add connection in-memory (8cb6ed3e-c2f6-4503-8e44-9d65152f118a,"br-3e8779b04137")
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4518] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4535] device (br-3e8779b04137): Activation: starting connection 'br-3e8779b04137' (8cb6ed3e-c2f6-4503-8e44-9d65152f118a)
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4542] manager: (br-9fbe4f319a5f): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4551] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4559] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4571] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4575] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4585] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4589] device (br-3e8779b04137): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i br-9fbe4f319a5f -o br-9fbe4f319a5f -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.4878] device (br-3e8779b04137): Activation: successful, device activated.
:37:48 localhost dbus[1378]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
:37:48 localhost systemd: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
:37:48 localhost dbus[1378]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
:37:48 localhost systemd: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
:37:48 localhost nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [br-3e8779b04137]: new request (2 scripts)
:37:48 localhost nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [br-3e8779b04137]: start running ordered scripts...
:37:48 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:48.583068746Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-9fbe4f319a5f already part of docker zone, returning"
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6789] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): br-9fbe4f319a5f: link is not ready
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6824] ifcfg-rh: add connection in-memory (d9c39609-5a81-4c0c-9a2e-66aed4a769bf,"br-9fbe4f319a5f")
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6832] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6845] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): Activation: starting connection 'br-9fbe4f319a5f' (d9c39609-5a81-4c0c-9a2e-66aed4a769bf)
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6852] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6861] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6870] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6883] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6887] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6898] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.6902] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
:37:48 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374668.7212] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): Activation: successful, device activated.
:37:48 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:48 localhost nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [br-9fbe4f319a5f]: new request (2 scripts)
:37:48 localhost nm-dispatcher: req:2 'up' [br-9fbe4f319a5f]: start running ordered scripts...
:37:48 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:48.814495830Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
:37:48 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
:37:49 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:49.329036411Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 07a00f7a6d448fbc2d424b3f40e02804e5a318da64747564069613b8680894a8 (826b5a8a1f54e393b2704df6f6161d240774360fc78f665459f004017a6309a9)"
:37:49 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:49.451171310Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 9fbe4f319a5f9615ad30da427efdfa1f4aec7433f05414ef8bca9a195c3fb1ae 4d3ae9beda19dbb5f6904cdab192f453fb7efb53ea08257ad1c8b56da3d5dc49], retrying...."
:37:49 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:49.789055062Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 8a51708abb7d4047eb5b1dc37065c52fcc4095574b1af7d460ba895ff450957a (6b7ada22c7c67fe09476330809be6777b9f0b30ba6fb052280b2a860cf2cd817)"
:37:49 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:49.917783912Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 9fbe4f319a5f9615ad30da427efdfa1f4aec7433f05414ef8bca9a195c3fb1ae 2d814c6e343c2187523c4fd3504d72241d4e346229d15d05eaa263a4c1e5398d], retrying...."
:37:50 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:50.252645870Z" level=info msg="Removing stale sandbox 969a0ae49869fe6699b82181e28ac7d4754d7e041e1f1c8ecc2cd8db14f8d6e4 (d2fd607cea68e1c6bf73bb07899a1b641a6cbf5171448b813e03003f071a99db)"
:37:50 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:50.367769949Z" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object [endpoint 9fbe4f319a5f9615ad30da427efdfa1f4aec7433f05414ef8bca9a195c3fb1ae 5a9b2d3871542132b1f81822324c08bd20ec61ba5f0eca22fce26e6c31b60965], retrying...."
:37:50 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:50.759406735Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
:37:50 localhost firewalld[1447]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
:37:50 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:50.900241442Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.1592] manager: (vethce38a65): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 1(veth3d2e2ec) entered blocking state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 1(veth3d2e2ec) entered disabled state
:37:51 localhost kernel: device veth3d2e2ec entered promiscuous mode
:37:51 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth3d2e2ec: link is not ready
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.1608] manager: (veth3d2e2ec): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.2200] manager: (veth8329e1f): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered blocking state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered disabled state
:37:51 localhost kernel: device veth94b8a31 entered promiscuous mode
:37:51 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth94b8a31: link is not ready
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered blocking state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered forwarding state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered disabled state
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.2216] manager: (veth94b8a31): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered blocking state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered disabled state
:37:51 localhost kernel: device veth43d2419 entered promiscuous mode
:37:51 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth43d2419: link is not ready
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered blocking state
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered forwarding state
:37:51 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-9fbe4f319a5f: link becomes ready
:37:51 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered disabled state
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.3787] manager: (veth891ba21): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/11)
:37:51 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374671.3804] manager: (veth43d2419): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/12)
:37:52 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:52.679931815Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/6b7ada22c7c67fe09476330809be6777b9f0b30ba6fb052280b2a860cf2cd817 pid=9731
:37:52 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:52.679927518Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/826b5a8a1f54e393b2704df6f6161d240774360fc78f665459f004017a6309a9 pid=9729
:37:52 localhost containerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:52.679885136Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/d2fd607cea68e1c6bf73bb07899a1b641a6cbf5171448b813e03003f071a99db pid=9730
:37:53 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:53Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
:37:53 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:53Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
:37:53 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:53Z" level=info msg="Firewalld: docker zone already exists, returning"
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth3d2e2ec: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 1(veth3d2e2ec) entered blocking state
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 1(veth3d2e2ec) entered forwarding state
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth43d2419: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered blocking state
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 3(veth43d2419) entered forwarding state
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth94b8a31: link becomes ready
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered blocking state
:37:53 localhost kernel: br-9fbe4f319a5f: port 2(veth94b8a31) entered forwarding state
:37:53 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374673.3167] device (veth3d2e2ec): carrier: link connected
:37:53 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374673.3173] device (br-9fbe4f319a5f): carrier: link connected
:37:53 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374673.3175] device (veth43d2419): carrier: link connected
:37:53 localhost NetworkManager[1455]: <info>  [1631374673.3180] device (veth94b8a31): carrier: link connected
:37:53 localhost dockerd: time="2021-09-11T:37:53.889460781Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
:39:29 localhost kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x42e, date = 2019-03-14
:39:29 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
:39:29 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
:39:29 localhost kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
:39:29 localhost kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the motherboard memory slot is not in good contact.
It is interesting to note that linux identify normal. Crash only on read or write to the memory slot and no any log can be found,even bios logs.

The greater the memory usage, the greater the crash probability